# IMemoryCache not instantiated in Class library

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm pretty new to ASP.Net Core, C#, OOP, Javascript … basically to everything I'm using at the moment. Last couple of months I've been reading and studying in order to start a new development project.
All in all I'm progressing steadily but I've bumped into an issue with IMemoryCache that I can't really get my head around (or is it with DI?).

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.0 and VS2017. I have a solution with 2 projects, my main ASP.Net Core MVC Web app and a .Net Core 2.0 Class Library.

In the Class Library I added a class in which I want to use caching so I added IMemoryCache to the constructor.
To instantiate the class I have another constructor that calls the function `GetModelGuidAsync`.

```
public class MdsEntityCRUD
    {
        #region ClassConstruct

        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        public MdsEntityCRUD(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }

        public MdsEntityCRUD(ServiceClient client, string modelName, string entityName, string versionFlag)
        {
            this.client = client;
            this.ModelId = Task.Run(async () => await GetModelGuidAsync(modelName)).Result;
            this.EntityName = entityName;
            mdsWS.Version ver = Task.Run(async () => await GetVersionByPolicyAsync(client, VersionPolicy.Flag, versionFlag, this.ModelId)).Result;
            this.VersionId = ver.Identifier.Id;
        }

        public async Task<Guid> GetModelGuidAsync(string modelName)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Guid> modelNames;

            if (!_cache.TryGetValue("ModelNames", out modelNames) || !modelNames.ContainsKey(modelName))
            {
                modelNames = await GetModelNamesAsync();
                _cache.Set("ModelNames", modelNames, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() { AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) });  // CFG
            }

            return modelNames[modelName];
        }
```

I've added *services.AddMemoryCache();* to ConfigureServices in Startup of my MVC project.
I'm calling the class from a Controller in my MVC project using the second constructor.
At runtime I get an error at the `if (!_cache.TryGetValue`-statement. These are the details shown in Exception Helper and from the exception window:

> System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=One or more
>   errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.)   Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   mdXmdsWS.MdsEntityCRUD..ctor(ServiceClient client, String modelName,
>   String entityName) in C:\Users..\MdsEntityCRUD.cs:line 59    at
>   MDS_MVC_Proto2.Controllers.DataExplorerController.EntityDataSource(DataManagerRequest
>   dmr) in C:\Users..\Controllers\DataExplorerController.cs:line 165
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>
> Inner Exception 1: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.
>
> ### and from ($exception).InnerException
>
> - InnerException  {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>     Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.TryGetValue[TItem](IMemoryCache
>     cache, Object key, TItem& value)    at
>     mdXmdsWS.MdsEntityCRUD.d__18.MoveNext() in
>     C:\Users..\MdsEntityCRUD.cs:line 84
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>     at
>     mdXmdsWS.MdsEntityCRUD.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>     in C:\Users..\MdsEntityCRUD.cs:line 59}  System.Exception
>     {System.NullReferenceException}

I don't know why I'm getting the error:
Is it because the cache is in the Class library and not in the MVC project?
Is it because I'm trying to use the cache in a function executed from the constructor?
Am I missing some configuration?

Eager to learn where I'm going wrong ...

Comment: Your second constructor doesn't have the `IMemoryCache` parameter in your constructor, so its null obviously. Also your second constructor suggetsts you are `new`-ing your class somewhere, since it has string parameters (which don't get resolved via .NET Cores Dependency Injection - unless you are using a 3rd party DI/IoC Framework such as Autofac etc.)

Comment: Just tried a few things based on your comment but this is where I get lost for 2 reasons: 1) from what I read about DI I understood that there is only 1 constructor containing the "to inject" classes and that you shouldn't mingle with other parameters??  2) when I add the IMemoryCache as parameter to the second constructor I need to pass an argument when instantiating the class (you are correct, I'm new-ing the class from my Controller) but I don't seem to be able to pass a valid argument as I can't create a **new** instance of IMemoryCache to pass as argument?

Comment: Dependency Injection doesn't work with magic. All DI does is the same you do when `new`-ing a class. Except, that some library does that for you and pass that to your class. When you `new`-ing your class, The IoC/DI Framework **WILL NOT BE INVOLVED**. Its no compiler magic (like async/await). As a rule of thumb: **never call `new` on types you want to inject**. Of course there are some exceptions to that (factories) and for non-services (models, pocos etc)

Comment: In other words: When you call `public MdsEntityCRUD(ServiceClient client, string modelName, string entityName, string versionFlag)` constructor, the `MdsEntityCRUD(IMemoryCache cache)` **WILL NOT BE INVOKED**. When you use DI/IoC you have to use it all the way down in your code, i.e. from controller to service to another service, to providers etc.

Comment: as for the second part of your comment: When you have to `new` your class, and pass the `IMemoryCache`, you need to inject `IMemoryCache` in your controller, then pass it to your class as parameter

Comment: Wouldn't we all want a little bit of magic now and then :-) ? I injected the cache in my controller and passed it to my class and it works fine now. Thanks!
One last question: how can I vote your comments as the correct answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, Dependency Injection (DI)/Inversion of Control (IoC) is no magic. At its very base, Dependency Injection just means: "Pass instance of object A to the constructor/method instead of `new`-ing it inside the constructor/method".

```
var service = new MyService(new MyDependency());
```

This above is already dependency injection, you inject a dependency to `MyService` and if its accepts a base class/interface, its implementation can be changed without changing `MyService`. This approach is commonly called "poor mans DI", without any external tools or libraries.

Then there are DI/IoC frameworks, which make that easier, so you don't have to `new` the instances yourself and inject it into the services as well as manage the objects live times for you (should every class get the same instance? (Singleton Lifetime) Or every time a new instance? (Transient Lifetime) Should specific group of classes get one instance and other group another ones? (Scoped Lifetime)).

When you use DI/IoC with or without a framework, you have to use it all the way down. There is no magic involved. The IoC frameworks do the same as above, `new`-ing a class and its dependencies and pass to the their constructors.

In case of ASP.NET Core the controller is resolved via the built-in DI/IoC Framework, so you can inject any registered class (inside Startup's `ConfigureServices` method).

In your case you obviously are `new`-ing the class with the second constructor, so the first one is never called and never setting the `_cache` member variable. When you try to access it, you get the dreaded `NullReferenceException` exception. You have to add the dependency to the main constructor.

If like in your case you like have to `new` a class, you have to pass the dependencies in yourself. In your case, you need to inject `IMemoryCache` into your controller and then pass it to your `new`-ed class.

IMemoryCache cache

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private readonly MdsEntityCRUD mdsCrud;

    public MyController(IMemoryCache memoryCache) 
    {
        ServiceClient client = ...;
        mdsCrud = new MdsEntityCRUD(memoryCache, client, "modelname", "entityName", "v1");
    }
}
```

This way you get the correct `IMemoryCache` instance from the Controller which you can pass to the services.

There are other, more elegant ways to abstract it (using factory classes or factory methods within `ConfigureServices`) to perform that, but its out of scope of the question.

Comment: thanks again. You not only solved my problem, you also gave the best explanation of DI I have come across so far.